# Wordpress Error custom taxonomy on post update term_taxonomy_id always 0

Tags: wordpress, taxonomy

im using Types Plugin for create custom post type,custom fields and taxonomys, but today i'm getting this error on phperror.log

```
[29-Feb-2016 16:29:12 UTC] WordPress database error Duplicate entry '5261-0' for key 'PRIMARY' for query INSERT INTO `wp_term_relationships` (`object_id`, `term_taxonomy_id`) VALUES (5261, 0) made by do_action('wp_ajax_inline-save'), call_user_func_array, wp_ajax_inline_save, edit_post, wp_update_post, wp_insert_post, wp_set_post_terms, wp_set_object_terms
```

term_taxonomy_id can not be 0, but i don't know how to fix this.

I tried

1 .- Delete and create new custom taxonomy with Types (does'n work)
2 .- Create a custom taxonomy from PHP code (same error)
3 .- Fill manually term_taxonomy_id (same error)

this error occurs when i save a post selecting custom taxonomy, then i "refresh" my wordpress panel and all taxonomies are selected for each post.

Is there anything i can do? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved! if someone have the same error, check that your table "wp_term_taxonomy" has "term_taxonomy_id" as auto-incremental, primary and unic options :)